# how to run "start-process test.bat " in powershell context

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I dont know if this is the right question that i am asking. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Query:

I am trying to run a windows Traffic tool "NTTtcp" using a batchfile.
I trigger the command remotely on to the windows as "start-process test.bat"

So the batchfile execution spawns a cmd window and executes there.

1) Is there a way to stop this spawning of a new window?
2) Is there a way to run the same in powershell mode rather than DOS mode
3) Is there a way to capture the output that is run on a new cmd window as i have used redirection operator and nothing works. Have also checked the possibility of clip too but that does not work too.

-Aprameya

Comment: No, to run a .bat, it has to open a new console window, the best you can do is open it minimized so that the "window doesn't pop-up". In regards to "can I run the same in powershell rather than cmd" it's most likely possible but that depends on the code, which you neglected to share in the body of your question. Put that up and clarify if you want a hidden window or just using PS instead of CMD and we might be able to help out.

Comment: Did you try this: `start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c test.bat" -NoNewWindow`

Comment: And I bet if you read the help for the `start-process` cmdlet you would see an example of redirecting standard output.

Answer (score 0):

For the running without a window, below is the code to add to the top of your batch which will launch it minimized as suggested by Andrew.

```
@echo off
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0" %*
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

As for a PowerShellequivalent of NTTtcp, I think you are SOL for something that well made. Maybe exporting the results from the CMD window to a .txt file and parsing them would be cleaner, if you are that hung up on having it in PowerShell.